# TV Mini Series with people that control Elements

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I remember seeing a live action TV mini series on American TV between 2001 and 2007ish.  It may have been on the Sci-Fi channel, but I am unsure.  I know for a fact it wasn't on any premium channels, such as HBO, Showtime, etc.  It only ran for 3-6 episodes, so it was definitely a mini-series. The show takes place in America.

In the show, there are two main characters, a protagonist and an antagonist.  The protagonist is played by someone that looks very similar to Billy Zane, but I am unable to find this in Bill Zane's [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000708/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1) list.  I believe the antagonist may have been Asian, but I am unsure.  I believe these two have been fighting for a long time, and use magical means to attack each other.

In the show, the protagonist ends up finding 3-4 Americans (2-3 men and at least one woman) that end up with special abilities to control different elements.  One was definitely water, I think another was fire.  These was a training montage with all of them and the water guy was soaked head to toe.  I think one of them may have been punching light bulbs.

At one point in the series, the bad guy psychically attacks the good guy's students, and I think one of them may have died.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Invincible](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0216487/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)

IMDb:

> "The Shadow Men are immortal beings of darkness and destruction. One
>   such Shadow Man, Os (Zane), is confronted by the White Warrior, a
>   being of light, and given the chance to change his ways or die. After
>   the White Warrior bests Os in combat, she opens his heart to the power
>   of love, and charges him to find **the warriors who are the
>   representation of the five elements** and will save the world from the
>   threat of the Shadow Men and their leader, Slate."

It was made in 2001, it has Billy Zane, good vs. evil, there is an [Asian guy](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0542677/?ref_=tt_cl_t2) in it and people controlling the elements. According to IMDb, it is a TV movie, so maybe it was aired as a 2-part mini-series.

Comment: are you kidding me?!  I looked SO many times and never saw this... thank you!

Comment: No problem. Initially, I was derailed by the mini-series thing.:)